# Why does Material UI use display flex [and not display grid]?

Tags: css, material-ui

> The grid system is implemented with the Grid component. It uses CSS's
> Flexible Box module for high flexibility.

Why material UI does not use a display grid as it uses display flex?

Comment: Any answers found on this topic ?

Answer (score 0):

Material UI uses both CSS grid and CSS flexbox for layout. If you wish to use CSS grid for layout then you can visit https://mui.com/system/grid/ and if you wish to use CSS flexbox for layout then you can use https://mui.com/components/grid/

Comment: I am talking about the actual Grid component by MUI

Comment: Yes, the actual Grid component is implemented with flex, I am also wondering why..
Also, I think you should edit the main question to make it more clear...